# Как организовать использование виджета alert с pjax

Tags: yii2

пытаюсь организовать вывод флеш сообщения Alertом при использовании pjax в виджете. 
вот собственно код     `Vidget.php`

```
namespace frontend\widget\vidget;

use yii\base\Widget;
use Yii;
class Videt extends Widget{
    public function init(){
        parent::init();
    }
    public function run(){
        $model= new Model();

        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            if($model->save()){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash([
              'success',
               'Спасибо операция окончена']
            );
               $this->render('html',[
                    'model'=>$model
             ]);
            }else{
             Yii::$app->session->setFlash([
              'error',
               'Извините произошла ошибка']
            );
              $this->render('html',[
                    'model'=>$model
             ]);
           }
        }else{
        return $this->render('html',[
            'model'=>$model
            ]);
    }
}
```

вот `views/html.php`

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Alert;
echo $this->render('_form',[
    'model'=>$model,
]);
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'reloded']);
    echo Alert::widget();
    Pjax::end();
$this->registerJs(
'$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#button").on("pjax:end", function() {
         $.pjax.reload({container:"#reloded"}); 
    });
});');
?>
```

`_form.php` не пишу поскольку сама форма работает и все сохраняется вот только после перезагузки pjax Alert не срабатывает. Как правильно это организовать не подскажите ?

Comment: нужно добавить js код алерта в место, где у Вас $.pjax.reload.

Comment: а какой код у алерта ?